# How to Creating Nested xml in Jaxb. I need to create xml as below

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I need to create xml as below using jaxb. I know how to create simle xml.But I have no idea regarding this nested xml.Please help me out with this. Thank you all

```
<whens>
    <when>
        <whenEntity1_Rule1>
            <whenAttribute1_Rule1>
                <whenCondition1_Rule1/>
                <whenValue1_Rule1>
                    <literalvalue1_Rule1/>
                    <whenEntity1_expression1_Rule1/>
                    <whenAttribute1_expression1_Rule1/>
                </whenValue1_Rule1>
            </whenAttribute1_Rule1>
            <whenAttribute2_Rule1>
                <whenCondition2_Rule1/>
                <whenValue2_Rule1>
                    <literalvalue2_Rule1/>
                    <whenEntity2_expression1_Rule1/>
                    <whenAttribute2_expression1_Rule1/>
                </whenValue2_Rule1>
            </whenAttribute2_Rule1>
            <whenAttribute3_Rule1>
                <whenCondition3_Rule1/>
                <whenValue3_Rule1>
                    <literalvalue3_Rule1/>
                    <whenEntity3_expression1_Rule1/>
                    <whenAttribute3_expression1_Rule1/>
                </whenValue3_Rule1>
            </whenAttribute3_Rule1>
        </whenEntity1_Rule1>
    </when> 
<whens>
```

Comment: I suggest you to extract an `XSD` from your `XML` and generate the classes using it by `maven-jaxb2-plugin`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [XSD generator](http://xmlgrid.net/xml2xsd.html) to extract the schema that describes the structure you've mentioned above.

You will then be add to add this schema to a JAXB marshaller or unmarshaller to generate JAXB objects and XML that is valid against the above structure. You can see how to do this in the answer to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18559552/add-schema-location-to-jaxb-unmarshaller)